# Convert existing input and table to Kendo Textbox and Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, responsive-design, kendo-mobile

I have a login form and I would like to kendofy it i.e. basically convert it into a responsive form like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index

Is there a quick way that would allow me to convert my existing username and password fields to kendo textbox fields such that I am able to achieve the responsive design without actually creating the fields again myself? Looking forward to your suggestions.

My Form:

```html
<form action="https://../Portal" method="post" name="loginForm">
  <input name="act" value="portalLogin" type="hidden">
  <input name="c" value="12912" type="hidden">
  <input name="p" value="101074" type="hidden">
  <input name="d" value="101076" type="hidden">
  <input name="g" value="101097" type="hidden">
  <input name="objDefId" value="13439" type="hidden">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="rbi_S_101098" name="Notification Message">
            <table class="wide rbwhite" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <table class="wide" height="10px">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="k-content" id="rbi_S_101100" name="User Login">
            <table class="wide rbwhite" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td nowrap="" align="right"><strong>Login Name&nbsp;</strong>
                          </td>
                          <td nowrap="">
                            <input class="k-textbox" name="loginName" maxlength="50" size="40" type="text">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="5">
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td nowrap="" align="right"><strong>Password&nbsp;</strong>
                          </td>
                          <td nowrap="">
                            <input class="k-textbox" name="password" maxlength="50" size="40" type="password">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="5">
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td></td>
                          <td alignmant="right" nowrap="">
                            <strong><input class="btn btn-small" value=" Login " type="submit"></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="5">
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td></td>
                          <td alignment="right" nowrap="">
                            <a href="https://../forgotPassword.jsp">Forgot your password?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <script>
                    document.loginForm.loginName.focus();
                  </script>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <table class="wide" height="10px">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="rbi_S_114558" name="Scripts Section">
            <table class="wide rbwhite" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="detailHTMLCol" colspan="2">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <table class="wide" height="10px">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry there is no automatic way of doing this. You need to change your fields manually...

Comment: That is a pain isn't it? I can understand the part of changing the fields, however how do I make it responsive automatically through kendo ui? Also could you post your answer as well please?